# Google Cloud Nav SDK error on Android intagration NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sdk, navigation

I am trying to integrate Google Cloud Navigation SDK for Android. Followed all steps in the documentation - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation/android-sdk/billing.
When I call NavigationTransactionRecorder.pickup() method I get the NullPointerException although none of two parameters (waypoint and transaction ID) are null.

```
NavigationTransactionRecorder transactionRecorder = NavigationApi.getTransactionRecorder(getApplication());

        pickUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                               

        
                                                Waypoint waypoint = Waypoint.builder().setLatLng(51.434110, -0.139030)
                                                        .setPreferSameSideOfRoad(true)
                                                        .setTitle("pickup waypoint")
                                                        .build();
                                    
                                                
                                                try {
                                                    transactionRecorder.pickup(

                                                            waypoint,
                                                            Arrays.asList(NavigationTransactionRecorder.generateTransactionId()));

                                                } catch (
                                                        NavigationTransactionRecorder.TransactionException e) {
                                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
        );
```

This is the error message below:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.libraries.navigation.NavigationTransactionRecorder.pickup(com.google.android.libraries.navigation.Waypoint, java.util.List)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I checked both parameters to be null and they are not null. I keep getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/navigation/NavigationApi#public-static-navigationtransactionrecorder-gettransactionrecorder-application-application),

> This class should be used if and only if your company is billed by
> Google on a per-transaction basis.
>
> A **Navigator** must be successfully obtained before calling this method,
> otherwise it will return **null**.
>
> If your project configuration prevents calling this method, it will
> return **null**.

It seems like one of these reasons could be the culprit.